# SpringBoot 2 + Junit5: null with @Value

Tags: spring-boot, junit, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have an application with SpringBoot2 and Junit5, and now I'm trying to make a test. I have a this class called OrderService that looks like this:

```java
@Component
public class OrderService {
@Value("#{'${food.requires.box}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> foodRequiresBox;

@Value("#{'${properties.prioritization}'.split(',')}")
private List<String> prioritizationProperties;

@Value("${further.distance}")
private Integer slotMeterRange;

@Value("${slot.meters.long}")
private Double slotMetersLong;
```

As you can see, the class has many @Value annotations that extracts values from application.properties file.

In the POM file I have these dependences:

```xml
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.junit.platform</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit-platform-launcher</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

Tn the **test/resources** folder I have the application.properties file with this information:

```
properties.prioritization:vip,food
food.requires.box:pizza,cake,flamingo
further.distance:2
slot.meters.long:0.5
```

The test file looks like this:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@TestPropertySource(locations="classpath:application.properties")
public class OrderServiceTest {
    OrderService orderService;

    @BeforeEach
    void before(){
        orderService = new OrderService();
    }

    @Test
    void findAll() {
        Order order = new Order().withDescription("2x Pizza with Salad\\n2x Kebab with Fries\\n1x Hot dog with Fries\\n2x Pizza with Fries");
        assertTrue(orderService.orderHasFood.test(order));
    }
}
```

But the test throws NullPointerException when it tries to use **foodRequiresBox**, so there is a problem to read the application.properties file.

Could you tell how can I read the application.properties file for the tests?

Comment: you need to run the spring context in your test if you need the values from the properties file. If you dont want to start the context you should use mockito and `.when`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1st Solution**

I would recommend to use Spring's internal annotation called `@SpringJUnitConfig`
This annotation is actually the same as `@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)` **BUT** you can configure your spring application contexts for your test in the same way you used to use `@ContextConfiguration`.

Or if you want a full Spring Boot Test you could just combine:

```
@SpringJUnitConfig
@SpringBootTest
public class OrderServiceTest {
...
}
```

**2nd Solution**

Another way is to not use Spring at all, but mock all the internal stuff with e.g. Mockito and write a plain simple Unit Test.
You could then set your normally via Spring injected annotated `@Value` fields via `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils`.

Comment: I would prefer second solution over first for lesser overhead of initializing the spring context

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils` (as indicated in @mrkernelpanic second solution) using the `setField()` method, in order to avoid initializing the full Spring context.

Here is a snippet:

```
// ReflexionTestUtils.setField(targetObject, "targetFieldName", valueToInject);
ReflexionTestUtils.setField(orderService, "foodRequiresBox", "pizza,cake,flamingo");
```